# Left join with multiple status

Tags: mysql, left-join

Lets say i have two stores. `Store A(22)` and `Store B(21)`. This is the query to fetch the things that matched with the Store ID:

```
SELECT c . * , s.s_name, s.logo, s.s_slug, cm.c_code, cm.c_shorturl, cm.c_shorturl_id
FROM ci_cptbl c
LEFT JOIN ci_stores s ON s.store_id = c.store_id
LEFT JOIN ci_cptbl_mapper cm ON cm.c_id = c._id
WHERE c.coupon_id <>  ''
AND c.store_id in ('22', '21')
AND s.s_status =  '1' 
AND c.c_status =  '1'
AND DATE( c.c_end_date ) >=  '2014-10-04'
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

`ci_cptbl` Has the collection of product including the `store_id`. And `ci_stores` holds the store name, etc.. including `s_status`(0, 1).

```
CREATE TABLE `ci_stores` (
 `store_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `cat_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `s_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `s_slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `logo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `display_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `s_description` text NOT NULL,
 `network_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `s_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `merged_stores` text NOT NULL,
 `stat` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`),
 KEY `network_id` (`network_id`),
 KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `display_name` (`display_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

[image: Sample]

Now condition is i have only first store id( `22` ) enabled and rest is disabled (21, .....) in my stores table and my `AND s.s_status =  '1'` statement works only if all the stores are enabled but i want all stores including disabled.

**BUT FIRST STORE ID MUST BE ENABLED**

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing you condition to test on store_id and enabled

```
(c.c_status =  '1' or c.store_id <> '22')
```

so:

```
SELECT c . * , s.s_name, s.logo, s.s_slug, cm.c_code, cm.c_shorturl, cm.c_shorturl_id
FROM ci_cptbl c
LEFT JOIN ci_stores s ON s.store_id = c.store_id
LEFT JOIN ci_cptbl_mapper cm ON cm.c_id = c._id
WHERE c.coupon_id <>  ''
AND c.store_id in ('22', '21')
AND s.s_status =  '1' 
AND (c.c_status =  '1' or c.store_id <> '22')
AND DATE( c.c_end_date ) >=  '2014-10-04'
ORDER BY c.c_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your "AND s.s_status = 1" clause to the LEFT JOIN part of your query.  When you move it to the WHERE clause, it forces to an implied INNER JOIN and thus leaving out of you result set.

```
     LEFT JOIN ci_stores s 
        ON c.store_id = s.store_id
       AND s.s_status =  '1'
```

Comment: this is what i want but the problem is if i disable both of the stores status then still its returing the result and in this condition it should not return result.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM ci_cptbl c
LEFT JOIN ci_stores s ON s.store_id = c.store_id
```

The purpose of that `LEFT JOIN` is to allow unmatched records in the "joined to" table to be listed in the results

e.g. if there is a store 657 in `ci_cptbl` but no such store in `ci_stores` 657 would still be listed

However, using the `WHERE clause`:

- if we then ALSO insist EVERY row has s.s_status =  '1'
- then store 657 would NOT be listed (how can it? it does not exist in `ci_stores` so `ci_stores`.`s_status` **has to be NULL** and can never ever be equal to 1

So; when using any outer join such as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you have to be very careful how you reference those tables in the `WHERE clause`. In many cases, such as here, it is better to move the additional condition(s) to the `JOIN` like this:

```
FROM ci_cptbl c
LEFT JOIN ci_stores s ON s.store_id = c.store_id
                      AND s.s_status =  '1'
```

Comment: mmm, I must be too slow.